# Is the continued fraction of the square root of a base $\phi$ (golden ratio) number periodic when the continued fraction is expressed in base $\phi$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, arithmetic, continued-fractions, periodic-functions, golden-ratio

I have been looking at concise ways to represent irrational numbers using only integers.

I was thinking about base $\phi$ ([golden ratio base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base)) and how it can represent the quadratic extension of the rationals with $\sqrt 5$ (i.e. $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 5]$) in a finite (potentially infinite but periodic) representation.  For example, $5 + \sqrt 5 = 10000.01$ exactly.

I also noticed that $\sqrt a$ always results in a periodic [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) (CF) when $a$ is a square-free integer.  The golden ratio $\phi$ is the least accurate irrational number to approximate by truncating its continued fraction, as it is [1, 1, 1, ...] (see Hurwitz's theorem and the Wikipedia Continued Fractions page).

Since truncating $\phi$'s CF is not as accurate a rational approximation as for other irrationals, and given that base $\phi$ allows us to represent $\phi$ concisely ($\phi = 10$) and allows a representation of integers (e.g. $2 = 10.01$), which is what CF's already use,

1. Are there any potential problems with using base $\phi$ as the base for a CF representation considering it gets around the accuracy issue for $\phi$ and allows continued fractions involving $\sqrt 5$ to be finite (I think)?
2. Is the continued fraction of the square root of a base $\phi$ number periodic when the CF is expressed in base $\phi$, in much the same manner as a square free integer?
3. Are there any other advantages/disadvantages to representing continued fractions in this base instead of another more typical base?

This is my first post, so please let me know if I need to correct anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the base for a CF representation".  In the most naive sense, continued fractions are completely independent of base.  It sounds like you would like to allow the terms $[a_0,a_1,\ldots]$ to be finite $\phi$-ary expansions rather than just integers?

Comment: @Erick: That is what I had in mind, but as both Steven and you point out, continued fractions are independent of base.  My mistake was that I wrongly understood independent of base to mean "compatible with any base that can represent integers" instead of "not using any base whatsoever".  I am fairly new to number theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'as the base for a CRF representation'; continued fraction representations, at heart, don't use bases at all - just integers.

Assuming that what you mean is allowing the coefficients of a standard continued fraction representation to be elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ rather than just $\mathbb{Z}$, then you run into trouble of a different source: in that case, there's no canonical CF representatation!  The usual algorithm for generating a canonical continued fraction uses the floor operation $\lfloor x\rfloor$ (that is, 'the largest integer less than $x$') : $a_0 = \lfloor x\rfloor, a_1=\lfloor\frac{1}{x-a_0}\rfloor$, etc.  But this operation can't be defined in $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ because the values in that ring are *dense* in the reals; there's no 'largest member less than $x$' for any $x$.

On the other hand, if you're interested in generalizing some of the properties of continued fractions to the ring of 'golden integers', there's another approach you could investigate:

As I'm sure you're already aware, the sequence of partial convergents to a continued fraction for some irrational number $x$ offers the best approximations to $x$, in a very canonical sense: each term $\frac{p}{q}$ in the sequence is the best approximation to $x$ of *height* less than $q$, where we define the height of a fraction $\frac{c}{d}$ in simplest terms to be just the denominator of the fraction.  In essence, the height represents the *simplicity* of the number, and the [best rational approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations) property says that no 'simpler' number than any of the partial convergents of the CF can be a better approximation.

You could try and generalize this property by defining a canonical height for golden integers (for instance, $\mathrm{ht}(a+b\phi) = \max(|a|, |b|)$ or even just $\mathrm{ht}(a+b\phi) = |b|$) and then studying the sequence of 'convergents' to a number $x$ using this height and the best-approximation property; this is in some sense similar to the continued fraction approach in that both are looking at the best approximation to $x$ of the form $f(a,b)$ for particular functions $f$ and integers $a,b$ less than some specified bound (and studying how that approximation changes as the bound moves) — in the case of continued fractions then $f(a,b) = \frac{a}{b}$ while here it's $f(a,b) = a+b\phi$.  It's very possible that the similarity of the problem means that these convergents have some canonical structure (similar to the way that the continued-fraction structure unites the best rational approximations) which you could use to define a continued-fraction equivalent for the representation by golden integers.  Speaking personally, I'd certainly be curious to see whether anything interesting came out of it!

Comment: Finding a continued fraction-like representation using an alternative definition of height is an interesting possibility that I'd like to explore, though I fear I lack the necessary expertise.  I welcome input from anyone who'd like to attempt it or comment on how to go about it.  On a related note, do continued fractions of square roots of a golden ratio base number (any or all) exhibit any sort of pattern (I know they're not periodic)?  If this should be a new question let me know.

Comment: So after doing a little more research, would a [generalized continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction) be able to represent the square root of a base-$\phi$ number in a periodic form?

Comment: @user35941 No, for an interesting reason: generalized continued fractions (with constant coefficients) are still essentially _projective linear transformations_ and so periodic GCFs can only represent quadratics. Basically, for a periodic GCF you'll still be left with an equation of the form $x=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ for the value of the GCF, and that's a quadratic equation in $x$.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding you, but are not quartic expressions like $x = \sqrt(5 + \sqrt 5)$ quadratic in base $\phi$ (e.g. $\sqrt(10000.01)$?  From what I've read of generalized continued fractions, the values used for numerator and denominator can be any real value, even $\pi$.

Comment: I think you're confusing a number with its representation - being quadratic isn't a property of a number with respect to some base(1); it's a property of the number itself (that it's the solution of a quadratic equation with integer coefficients). And while GCFs can use any coefficients, for concreteness you really want to restrict the coefficients to some particular meaningful set; otherwise CF representations are trivial.  (1) : one can talk meaningfully about _quadratic extensions_, but that's another matter.)

Comment: That said, I think I understand what you're getting at, but further explanation will have to wait until I'm typing on a non-thumb keyboard...

Comment: I understand that a number and it's representation are distinct, but I am confused as to why a generalized continued fraction who's numerator and denominator contain the number $\sqrt 5$ (whatever it's representation) would not periodically converge for something like $\sqrt(5 + \sqrt 5)$ given that the fraction will converge using any positive real value.  See [the convergence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_problem) and [this page](http://tedmuller.us/Math/SpecialContinuedFraction.htm).  I appreciate the comments, as this is a new subject for me.

Comment: To elaborate, I think (but am not certain) that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 5]$ can be just such a set of meaningful coefficients.  I don't think integers alone are the only appropriate set of coefficients for a generalized continued fraction, and I'd like to see if other sets provide advantages for representing certain numbers.

Comment: You're essentially correct that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{5}\right]$ can be the set of coefficients for a (general) continued-fraction representation; what you lose, though (or at least what I'm fairly confident you'll lose) is _uniqueness_; there will be infinitely many such representations, and you have to come up with some canonical means for choosing which one you want.  That said, you _are_ right that the GCF (or even standard CF) should be able to periodically represent any number in your quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{5}\right]$.

Answer (score 2):

Steven has given an excellent answer, but I fear many people will not read all the comments and decide that the answer is basically no instead of yes due to the loss of a canonical form of continued fractions.

I will now try to demonstrate how to go about finding a good representation for base-$\phi$ square roots and why this might be useful.

It turns out that the sine or cosine of any integer multiple of $\pi/60$ can be represented as a linear combination of the following 6 factors (see [Exact Trigonometric Constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_constants#Table_of_constants)):

$1$

$\sqrt 2$

$\sqrt 3$

$\sqrt 5$

$\sqrt{5+\sqrt 5}$

$\sqrt{5-\sqrt 5}$

Except for 1, these are basically quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q$.

I want to represent a subset of the [constructable numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_numbers) that use only sines and cosines of angles
$\dfrac{n\pi}{60}$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$.

[Generalized continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Roots_of_positive_numbers) (GCF) allow me to represent square roots using the following formula (see [Methods of Computing Square Roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Generalized_continued_fraction)):
$\sqrt z = \sqrt{x^2 + y} = x + \dfrac{y}{2x + \dfrac{y}{2x + \dfrac {y}{2x + \dfrac{y}{\ddots}}}}$

where $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, thus guaranteeing convergence as long as the product of successive $2x$'s grows faster than the product of successive $y$'s (see the [Convergence Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_problem)).  Generally we want $x$ to be as large as possible and $y$ to be as small as possible for faster convergence.

For $\sqrt 2$, $x = 1$ and $y = 1$.
For $\sqrt 3$, x = 1 and $y = 2$ does not converge quickly. Let's take a look in [base-$\phi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base).
$3 = 100.01 = \phi^2 + \phi^{-2}$ so $x = \phi$ and $y = \phi^{-2}$ will give much faster convergence.  You might wonder if $\sqrt 2$ has a similar faster convergence, but as $2 = 10.01 = \phi + \phi^{-2}$ we don't have an easy way to represent $x$ as $\sqrt \phi$.  If we re-write it as $2 = 1.11 = 1 + \phi^{-1} + \phi^{-2}$ we can take the $1$ for $x$ leaving $y = 0.11 = 1.00 = 1$ for $y$, which simply recovers $x = 1$ and $y = 1$.

$\sqrt 5$ is already directly representable in base-$\phi$, but if we wanted to use integers, $x = 2$ and $y = 1$ works just fine, and base-$\phi$ for $5$ doesn't give us a better convergence.

Now for the fun part.
$5 + \sqrt 5 = 10000.01 = \phi^4 + \phi^{-2}$, so $x = \phi^2$ and $y = \phi^{-2}$ will give good convergence, and
$5 - \sqrt 5 = 100.0001 = \phi^2 + \phi^{-4}$, so $x = \phi$ and $y = \phi^{-4}$ will give good convergence, both in a finitely representable periodic form.

Combinations of these factors like $\sqrt 6 = \sqrt 2\sqrt 3$ (for $15^\circ$) and $\sqrt 2\sqrt{5 + \sqrt 5}$ (for $12^\circ$) are also periodic GCF's.

This gives us a nice finite way to represent vectors made from sines and cosines of integer multiples of $3^\circ$.

So to answer my original questions:

1. Yes. One problem is that uniqueness is lost for CF representations.  There are infinitely many ways to represent the same CF.  This is related to the problem base-$\phi$ has in that there are infinitely many finite ways to represent the same number (using the 100 = 011 conversion).  This is not a problem as long as we can find a consistent representation for numbers we are interested in.
2. Yes, at the cost of uniqueness.
3. One advantage is potentially faster convergence of a GCF than with only integers.  Another is the ability to represent quadratic extensions (square roots) of $\mathbb Z[\phi]$ in a periodic form.

Comment: @Steven, please let me know if I missed anything important or made any serious mistakes.